# is it possible to have ngAnimation without adding any class for all the ng-if across application?

Tags: angularjs, animation

I have referred so many answers for this but the problem is we have already written so many things in our web app. and now i want to add animation for ng-if across all without going and adding classes to all ng-if divs.

So what can be best approach to do it.

Comment: You mean, If there is an ng-if to a div, It should be animated right? without adding any classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the animation you want for all elements with `ng-if` in CSS like you normally would.

For example:

```
.my-animation.ng-enter,
.my-animation.ng-leave {
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.my-animation.ng-enter,
.my-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.my-animation.ng-leave,
.my-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Add a directive that adds the `my-animation` class to all elements with `ng-if`:

```
app.directive('ngIf', function() {

  return {
    compile: function(tElement) {

      tElement.addClass('my-animation');
    }
  }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/p88E3VxVdPw0WWpbfJXG?p=preview